# while loop termination if end of file reached

Tags: python, file, while-loop, increment, termination

while loop termination if end of file reached

Comment: Why are you using `while` not `for`? Where is the full error traceback? What are `sPos` and `ePos` and `genMaPos`; do they ever change, and if so, where?

Comment: I did some modification @jonrsharpe u can see it now

Comment: you can use a `try-except` block.

Comment: @jonrsharpe here it is .

Comment: @salman can you help me with the syntax?

Comment: I need to see more of your code, as in paste the functions you wrote. Currently i don't understand it clearly.

Comment: the `try-except` syntax is simple. you can easily learn it by goggling.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, the file object implements the `__iter__` interface, so that you can do:

```
for line in file:
   # processing on line
```

My recommendation would be to restructure the code this way, breaking early if necessary. Ex:

```
for line in file:
  if processed_count >= max_lines_to_process:
     break
  # ....
  processed_count += 1
```

Comment: Thank you @Michael I did some modification on my question explaining why I needed to use while loop. and I don't know if for loop can help in my case

Comment: It's still not clear why you need to structure it this way. It looks like you always read from the file, the only difference is "if genMaPos >= sPos and genMaPos < ePos", you appear to also do some additional computation. There's also the problem that you don't appear to increment "sPos" or "ePos", so it is unclear how these loops are ever expected to terminate.

Comment: I always read from a file in these two cases. but if genMaPos > ePos which is not stated explicitly in the code, it will not move to next line . he'll move to next cluster and perform the rest of operations on the same line. @Michael